# Reload page on language change in google translator

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-translate

I have used following code to change website language

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
         new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage:'en',includedLanguages: 'en,zh-CN,zh-TW,es,fr', layout:google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');

  }

//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit
```

It is working fine,but the issue is,as language changes I want to relaod the page.To accomplish it I have tried following codes.

```
1.$('a.goog-te-menu2-item').on('click',function(){


        console.log("span test");

          location.reload();
});


This code is not working
```

```
2.$('.goog-te-menu-value').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {

     location.reload();
 });


The second one reload page too many times.
```

Please guide me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the selector element in your case? Is it a dropdown or radio button. It would help if you can give more code related to it.

Comment: yes it is drop down and I have hide google translator banner with css<b> .goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
        display: none !important;
        }</b>

Comment: Getting Iframe code with-<tr valign="top"><td><a class="goog-te-menu2-item-selected" href="javascript:void(0)"><div style="white-space: nowrap;">
<span class="indicator">›</span><span class="text">Select Language</span></div></a><a class="goog-te-menu2-item" href="javascript:void(0)"><div style="white-space: nowrap;"><span class="indicator">›</span><span class="text">Chinese (Simplified)</span></div></a><a class="goog-te-menu2-item" href="javascript:void(0)"><div style="white-space: nowrap;"><span class="indicator">›</span><span class="text">Chinese (Traditional)</span></div> </a></td></tr>

Comment: @Sadique can you please suggest me any solution?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to reload the page from an Iframe. May i right? If Yes then did you try `window.top.location.reload();`

Comment: But,I want to reload on '.goog-te-menu2-item' click event,Unable to fire click event on this class

Comment: Its more than two weeks.I didn't get any solution.